# Cómo hacer un buscador que cuando obtenga un resultado que exista en la base de datos me dirija a la página del resultado

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo creado un buscador. Al escribir la ciudad, si esta existe en la Base de Datos, quiero que me abra la página de esa ciudad.
Tengo diez ciudades con información específica, pero el buscador está en la página genérica, donde muestro los enlaces a esas ciudades y otras informaciones, y lo que estoy tratando de hacer, es que al poner una ciudad, la busque en la base de datos y si esta existe, me abra una página con la información de esa ciudad.

Les adjunto el código del buscador. Es para hacerlo con PHP.

```
    <div class="buscador>
        <form action="" method="post" name="fbuscar" id="fbuscar" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <div class="buscador-input">
                <label for="q" class="input-label">¿Escribe la ciudad?</label>
                <input type="search" name="q" id="q" class="input-tex">
            </div>
            <div class="buscador-submit">
                <label for="bbuscar" class="submit-label">
                <input type="submit" name="bbuscar" id="bbuscar" value="BUSCAR" class="submit-btn">          
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>        
        <div id="mensajeError" class="alertError alertError-dnone"></div>
    </div>
```

El código funciona perfectamente, pero tengo un problema y es que la página se recarga, y no me gustaría que hiciese eso. Estoy viendo si puedo hacerlo con AJAX; todo me funciona bien, hasta aquí, pero no sé como puedo capturar la variable `($slug)` del archivo `verificar-ciudades.php` y devolverla al archivo principal, para que esta acción me envíe a la ciudad seleccionada.

`window.location.href="/visita-$slug";`

Tampoco sé si esto se podrá hacer.

Este es el código del archivo principal, donde está el formulario.

```
$( function(){
        $("#fbuscar").submit(function(event){ 
            event.preventDefault();           
            enviar();
        }); //#fbuscar
    
        function enviar(){ 
            //                
            $("#proceso").val("Buscar");
            var datos = $("#fbuscar").serialize(); 
            //    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  "verificar-ciudades.php",
                data: datos,                    
                success: function(texto){  
                    if(texto == "exito"){  
                        $("#q").val(''); 
                        //Aquí es donde tengo el problema, que no sé como 
                         capturar esta variable ($slug) en verificar- 
                         ciudades.php y devolverla a este archivo, para 
                         ejecutar el código de abajo.      
                        
                          window.location.href="/visita-$slug";   
                         
                    }else{                           
                        phperror(texto);                            
                    }
                }                    
            });
        }            
    });  
    
    function phperror(texto){                
        $("#mensajeError").removeClass("alertError--d-none");  
        $("#mensajeError").html(texto);
        setTimeout(function() {   
            $("#mensajeError").html('');           
        }, 5000);
    
    }
```

Y este es el código de `verificar-ciudades.php`

```
<?php 
    require_once 'modulo/conexion.php'; 
    require_once 'modulos-funciones/funciones-validar-ajax.php'; 
    // 
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        //
        $error    = '';
        $proceso  = validar_input_datos($_POST['proceso']);
        $ciudad   = validar_input_datos($_POST["q"]);     
        //        
        $expresion ="/^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]*$/";  
        //      
        if(empty($ciudad)){
            $error = 'Ingresa una Ciudad </br>';
        }else{      
            //
            if( preg_match($expresion, $ciudad) ){
                $ciudad =  $ciudad;  
            }else{
                $error .='Solo letras';
            }
        }
        //
        if ($proceso == 'Buscar' && $error == '' && $ciudad !='') {  
            $sql = $conexion->prepare("SELECT ciu_slug FROM ciudades 
            WHERE ciu_nombre =:cd AND ciu_estado = 1"); 
            $sql->bindValue(":cd", $ciudad, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sql->execute();
            $fila = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            
            if( isset($fila['ciu_slug']) ){                
                $slug = $fila['ciu_slug'];                
                //                
                echo 'exito';                  

            }else{
                echo'En ' .$ciudad ." No disponemos de información";
            }                
                              
        }else{
            echo $error;   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo simple, donde el PHP recibe el dato de tu formulario, hace la consulta y si arroja una coincidencia con **header('location:URL')** de PHP redirigimos, en esta parte tu puedes jugar con las urls, ya sea hacer un caso para cada URL o utilizar una variable para modificar la ruta, eso ya queda a tu criterio. En el caso de que la respuesta sea nula o 0, ejecuta un alert, indicando que no se encontró dicha ciudad.

```js
<?php
include 'Aqui tu URL de conexion';

if(isset($_POST['q'])){
  $ciudad = $_POST['q'];
  
    $sql="SELECT ciudad FROM tabla WHERE ciudad like '%$ciudad%'"; //Prepara consulta
    $result=$conn->query($sql); //Ejecuta consulta
    //recorrer las rows que arrojo la consulta, si tiene datos redirigimos
    if($result->num_rows>0){
     header('location: URL de la pagina de la ciudad');
     //Podria ser tambien de esta forma, completando la URL con la variable enviada, seria mas dinamico
     //header('location: localhost/ciudades/'.$ciudad.'.php');
    }else{//si esta vacio muestra el alert
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("No se encontro esa ciudad");
    </script>';
    }
}
?>
```

Hay muchas formas, pero te dejo una sencilla, dime si te sirvió.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y por tu tiempo. El código funciona perfectamente, pero tengo un problema y es que la página se recarga, y no me gustaría que hiciese eso. Lo he intentado con AJAX, pero no lo doy hecho. He subido el código que hice.

Comment: No me funciona, pero se agradece.

Comment: No se comprende lo que quieres realmente, date una vuelta en la documentación de Ajax, quieres obtener un dato de PHP con Ajax?, pz el resultado tiene que ser devuelto en un **echo** por PHP, de lo contrario Ajax no Obtendra nada en el success.